# Angular 2: No provider for ConnectionBackend! How to solve?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I was following this tutorial here https://tableless.com.br/criando-uma-aplicacao-movel-com-ionic-2-e-angular-2-em-dez-passos/ but things dind't go as expectend and I got stuck in a "No provider for..." error. (The tutorial is in Portuguese, but I think you'll get it only by looking at the code examples.)

The code is like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  public feeds: Array<string>;
  private url: string = "https://www.reddit.com/new.json";  
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {
    this.http.get(this.url).map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.feeds = data.data.children;
      }); 
  }
}
```

First, the error was for "Http".
Then I (think I) solved with this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  providers: [Http],
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
```

But now the error is a "No provider for ConnectionBackend!", and I don't know how to solve.

Comment: 1. You shouldn't really access `Http` directly from a component, do it from a service. 2. Also you shouldn't be specifying `providers` in the component, do it at a module level; in this case, there should be an `imports` array somewhere with `HttpModule` in it. Both of these things are covered in the Angular tutorial: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: No provider for http in constructor parameter with Ionic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43377588/error-no-provider-for-http-in-constructor-parameter-with-ionic)

Comment: thanks for the tutorial link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the HttpModule to the imports in the app.module.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpModule, <----
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```