# ionic2/3 get and post not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am new to ionic2 (but a vintage in programming in general), and trying my hands in ionic2. Now, I am trying to make a simple get/post to my web services (running locally in development) and I simply can't just get the services called.

Funny thing is that the get and post calls do not cause any errors/warnings/anything else.

---

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

import { BackgroundGeolocation } from '@ionic-native/background-geolocation';

import { Geolocation, Geoposition } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

@Injectable()
export class LocationTracker {
    public watch: any;
    public lat: number = 0;
    public lng: number = 0;
    public http: Http;

    constructor(public zone: NgZone, public backgroundGeolocation: BackgroundGeolocation,
        public geolocation: Geolocation, http: Http) {
            this.http = http;
    }

    public postLocationData(lat: number, lng: number)  {
        var JSONObject = {"latitude": "" + lat, "longitude": "" + lng };

        console.log("Posting: " + JSON.stringify(JSONObject));
        let headerOptions: any = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
        let headers = new Headers(headerOptions);

        // The simple get service. Curl from command line works
        this.http.get("http://192.168.1.2:8080/location/new1/")
        .map((response: Response) => {
            console.log('Response is: ' + response);
        })
        .catch((this.handleErrorObservable));

        // The simple post service. Curl from command line works. Note that in the service, the post param is captured as a String (Java) and then I am casting the string to an Object using Gson
        this.http.post("http://192.168.1.2:8080/location/new/", JSON.stringify(JSONObject), new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }))
        .map((response: Response) => {
            console.log('Response is: ' + response);
        })
        .catch((this.handleErrorObservable));
    }

    startTracking() {
        // lat and lng are populated here
    }

    stopTracking() {
        // something ...
    }
    private handleErrorObservable (error: Response | any) {
        console.error('Error in handleErrorObservable: ' + ( error.message || error ) );
        return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

---

A similar snippet also appears in a pastebin which I posted (https://pastebin.com/f39vW1hD). Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Without the subscribe or async pipe, you cannot see the requests sent.

```
public postLocationData(lat: number, lng: number)  {
    var JSONObject = {"latitude": "" + lat, "longitude": "" + lng };

    console.log("Posting: " + JSON.stringify(JSONObject));
    let headerOptions: any = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
    let headers = new Headers(headerOptions);

    // The simple get service. Curl from command line works
    this.http.get("http://192.168.1.2:8080/location/new1/")
    .map((response: Response) => {
        console.log('Response is: ' + response);
    })
    .subscribe(data => console.log(data));

    // The simple post service. Curl from command line works. Note that in the service, the post param is captured as a String (Java) and then I am casting the string to an Object using Gson
    this.http.post("http://192.168.1.2:8080/location/new/", JSON.stringify(JSONObject), new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }))
    .map((response: Response) => {
        console.log('Response is: ' + response);
    })
    .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
}
```

Comment: Excellent it worked. Thank you. I needed to do a something else as well to avoid ConnectionBackEnd issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43413527/angular-2-no-provider-for-connectionbackend-how-to-solve

Comment: Another question. I see this to be async call .. how can I make it sync call ? Or it is not suggested to make a sync call ?

Comment: You can still use flatmap operator refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/38875576/8011544 But you should know that in general you need to separate the post & get request in two separate methods